# old custom php code admin panel login issue

Tags: php

I have a problem with admin login for a site.
The site was custom coded from scratch by a developer 7-8 years back. It runs on php 5.3 version. 
I  recently moved the website, to a new server with better configuration. 
Ever since the website was moved to this server, i am not able to login to the custom coded admin control of the website.

i am not able to figure out what exactly i am missing

**data.php code**

```
<?
session_start();

$dbh = @mysql_connect('localhost','mangal_nwwwman','Mangu@123');

mysql_select_db("mangal_qmangi", $dbh);
if (!$dbh) {
  echo "ERROR: There was an error connecting to the database server.  Please try again later.";
  exit;
}
/*if (!@mysql_select_db("mangal_qmangi", $dbh)) {
  echo "ERROR: There was an error connecting to the database.  Please try again later.";
  exit;
}*/
function dateconverter ($data) {
    $date = substr($data,5,2)."-".substr($data,8,2)."-".substr($data,0,4);
    return $date;

}
include("security.php");
?>
```

**security.php code**

```
<?
if(!isset($userid)){
if((!isset($PHP_AUTH_USER)) && (!isset($PHP_AUTH_PW))) {
    Header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Mangalorean.com Admin Security System\"");
    Header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
    echo  "Authentication Problem...\n";
    exit;
    }else{
    $query = "select * from managers where username='$PHP_AUTH_USER' and password='$PHP_AUTH_PW'";
    $manager_query = mysql_query($query);
    echo mysql_error();
    $manager_row = mysql_fetch_array($manager_query);
    if ($manager_row>0)
        {
        $username=$PHP_AUTH_USER;
        $userid=$manager_row[userid];
        $permission=$manager_row[permission];
        $name=$manager_row[name];
        session_start();
        session_register ("userid");
        session_register ("permission");
        session_register ("name");
        header("location:index.php");
        exit;
    }
    }
    Header( "WWW-authenticate:  Basic  realm=\"Mangalorean.com Admin Security System\"");
    Header( "HTTP/1.0  401  Unauthorized");
    echo  "<b>Authentication Problem...</b><br><br>Contact the administrator.";
    exit;
}
?>
```

can anybody help me understand what is happening, and why is this not working?

Comment: Without the error, it's hard to tell. However, mysql_* functions are deprecated, and removed completely in PHP 7. You will want to change those lines to use either PDO or mysqli.

Comment: @aynber I have made sure the server we migrated to is also running 5.3 version of php. I am on a dedicated machine.

Comment: @aynber there are no errors i can check anywhere. no errorlog is been generated. all that happens is, wen i put in the username and the password, it comes back to the same login page

Comment: if you can ssh the server try this php -i | grep "error_log" this will return you the basic error_log file, if its value is empty you need to set it in php.ini then retry then check that log file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that "short_open_tag" is enabled in your php.ini, otherwise you won't be able to use

```
 <?
```

as a start tag.

Using

```
<? //instead of <?php
```

Is now deprecated as it has to be configured first.